# migrar stored procedure sql server a postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedure

soy nuevo usando postgresql, tengo un stored procedure en sql server y me gustaria pasarlo a postgresql, mi problema es creando una tabla temporal y ejecutandolo, me da el error de que no existe , en sql ejecuto el stored procedure usando exec, en postgresql, buscando informacion he encontrado que usan execute, pero me marca error al usarlo, igual intente con select * from sp_temp, y se crea con exito el stored procedure(function)pero al ejecutarlo me da error, de que sp_temp no existe

este es mi stored procedure en sql server

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_obtener_curso_paginacion](
        @NombreCurso nvarchar(500),
        @Ordenamiento nvarchar(500),
        @NumeroPagina int, 
        @CantidadElementos int,
        @TotalRecords int OUTPUT,
        @TotalPaginas int OUTPUT
    
    )
    AS 
    
    
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    
    
            DECLARE @Inicio int
            DECLARE @Fin int
    
            IF @NumeroPagina = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @Inicio = (@NumeroPagina*@CantidadElementos) - @CantidadElementos
                    SET @Fin = @NumeroPagina * @CantidadElementos
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @Inicio = ((@NumeroPagina*@CantidadElementos)- @CantidadElementos) + 1
                    SET @Fin = @NumeroPagina * @CantidadElementos
                END
    
                /*TABLA TEMPORAL QUE ALMACENA LOS DATOS QUE SE VAN INFILTRANTO*/
                CREATE TABLE #TMP(
                rowNumber int IDENTITY(1,1),
                ID uniqueidentifier
                )
    
                /*se crea una variable que represente la tabla*/
                DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
                SET @SQL = ' SELECT CursoId FROM Curso '
    
                IF @NombreCurso IS NOT NULL
                    BEGIN 
                        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE Titulo LIKE ''%' + @NombreCurso + '%'' '
                    END
    
                IF @Ordenamiento IS NOT NULL
                    BEGIN
                        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ORDER BY ' + @Ordenamiento
                    END
                    
                --SELECT CursoId FROM Curso WHERE Titulo Like '% ASP %' ORDER BY Titulo
    
                INSERT INTO #TMP(ID)
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    
                SELECT @TotalRecords = Count(*) FROM #TMP
    
                IF @TotalRecords > @CantidadElementos 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @TotalPaginas = @TotalRecords / @CantidadElementos
                        IF (@TotalRecords % @CantidadElementos) > 0
                            BEGIN 
                                SET @TotalPaginas = @TotalPaginas + 1
                            END
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @TotalPaginas = 1
                    END
SELECT 
                c.CursoId,
                c.Titulo,
                c.Descripcion,
                c.FechaPublicacion,
                c.FotoPortada,
                c.FechaCreacion,
                
                FROM #TMP t INNER JOIN dbo.Curso c 
                            ON t.ID = c.CursoId

                WHERE t.rowNumber >= @Inicio AND t.rowNumber <= @Fin    

    END
```

y aqui he creado la funcion en postgresql, pero obtengo error de sp_executesql no existe, igual quite el --SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ; porque me marca error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 12:   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

como puedo pasar mi stored procedure a function en postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usp_obtener_curso_paginacion(
    p_NombreCurso varchar(500),
    p_Ordenamiento varchar(500),
    p_NumeroPagina int, 
    p_CantidadElementos int,
    p_TotalRecords int,
    p_TotalPaginas int 

)
RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
        --SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
        DECLARE v_Inicio int;
     v_Fin int;
     v_SQL text;
     BEGIN


        IF p_NumeroPagina = 1
            THEN
                v_Inicio := (p_NumeroPagina*p_CantidadElementos) - p_CantidadElementos;
                v_Fin := p_NumeroPagina * p_CantidadElementos;
        ELSE
                v_Inicio := ((p_NumeroPagina*p_CantidadElementos)- p_CantidadElementos) + 1;
                v_Fin := p_NumeroPagina * p_CantidadElementos;
            END IF;

            -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
            CREATE SEQUENCE TMP_seq;

            CREATE TABLE TMP(
            rowNumber int DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('TMP_seq'),
            ID char(36)
            );

         
            v_SQL := ' SELECT CursoId FROM Curso ';

            IF p_NombreCurso IS NOT NULL
                THEN 
                    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' WHERE Titulo LIKE ''%' || p_NombreCurso || '%'' ';
                END IF;

            IF p_Ordenamiento IS NOT NULL
                THEN
                    v_SQL := v_SQL || ' ORDER BY ' || p_Ordenamiento;
                END IF;
                
            INSERT INTO TMP(ID)
            SELECT * FROM sp_executesql v_SQL;

            -- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
            SELECT Count(*) INTO p_TotalRecords FROM TMP;

            IF p_TotalRecords > p_CantidadElementos 
                THEN
                    p_TotalPaginas := p_TotalRecords / p_CantidadElementos;
                    IF (p_TotalRecords % @CantidadElementos) > 0
                        THEN 
                            p_TotalPaginas := p_TotalPaginas + 1;
                        END IF;
            ELSE
                    p_TotalPaginas := 1;
                END IF;

SELECT 
            c.CursoId,
            c.Titulo,
            c.Descripcion,
            c.FechaPublicacion,
            c.FotoPortada,
            c.FechaCreacion
            

            FROM #TMP t INNER JOIN Curso c 
                        ON t.ID = c.CursoId
                        
    
            WHERE t.rowNumber >= v_Inicio AND t.rowNumber <= v_Fin;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ejecutar un SQL dinámico debes utilizar un `EXECUTE`

```
EXECUTE ' INSERT INTO TMP(ID) SELECT * FROM '|| v_SQL;
```

¿Esa última sentencia(SELECT) en la función es para retornar datos? Si es asi debes definir tu función como un `SETOF` o de tipo `TABLE` con el nombre de las columnas y el tipo de dato y no `VOID` como haces.

Comment: si, es para retornar los datos de la tabla

Comment: y al hacer el cambio que me dices me da error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO TMP(ID) SELECT * FROM SELECT id FROM curso`

Comment: Entonces tu VSQL viene con todo, debes hacer esto:
EXECUTE ' INSERT INTO TMP(ID)  '|| v_SQL;

Comment: para retornar los datos de la tabla debes definir las columnas y tipos de datos que vas a retornar en la opcion TABLE (columna1 varchar ....) en el return de la funcion